# Types of Mathematics used for horse racing probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A top jockey with a career strike rate of 17% has 6 rides on a race program.
What is the probability he/she will ride at least 1 winner for the day?

Also, what methods are used to calculate regression/mean reversion?

I'm considering studying maths.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the probability that they will lose all of the six races?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Fair enough, but i'm not mathematically educated. I'm trying to work out   which subjects to study at university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, the chance that he/she loses each individual race is $1 - 0.17 = 0.83$. If the races are independent the then probability that she loses them all is $0.83^6$. Subtract that from $1$ for the probability of at least one win.

The second question is too vague for an answer other than "there are formulas for that". Excel knows them and you will learn them when you study statistics.

(For future reference for this site - if you were already a math student I wouldn't have answered this question, since you show no work of your own on it.)

**Edit** in response to comment. Assuming "strike rate" means "probability of winning", 
$$
1 - (1 - 0.17)^6 = 
0.67
$$
is the probability of winning at least one race out of $6$. For one race out of $100$ the probability is
$$
1 - (1 - 0.17)^{100} = 0.99999999191
$$
so essentially a sure thing. All those decimal places make no real sense.

Comment: So you are claiming the jockey has a 17% chance of riding at least 1 winner for the day out of 6 rides? What if he/she has 100 rides?